# creating controller doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I'm learning asp.net mvc3 from w3schools and following that tutorial.http://w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_models.asp In the section "ASP.NET MVC Models" I have created the model like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcDemo.Models
{
    public class MovieDB
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Director { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MovieDB> Movies { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Then I was going to add a controller according to the instructions.

- In the Solution Explorer, right-click the Controllers folder, and select Add and Controller
  Set controller name to MoviesController
- Select template: Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework
- Select model class: MovieDB (McvDemo.Models)
- Select data context class: MovieDBContext (McvDemo.Models)***
- Select views Razor (CSHTML)
- Click Add

But the problem I have is that the drop down list doesn't show MovieDB (McvDemo.Models) in Model Class and Data Context Class to be selected. Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: recompile your code Build->BuildSolution then try it, magic!

Comment: @Daniel I learned a lot from w3schools back-in-the-day. There aren't a lot of beginner tutorials out there and they do a job.

Comment: my 2cents.. http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/  great tutorial to learn MVC :)

Comment: Thank you Liam, Tony for answering me, It worked. @Tony, sir thanks for the tutorial u sent me. I'll study that. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools. Ever.

Comment: Kino check this out about w3 :) http://w3fools.com/

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to recompile (Shift-Ctrl-B) and then try it again - it will be there.  Otherwise you can always just declare it yourself at the top of a blank view, but that will not provide the scaffolding that the generator does:

```
@model MvcDemo.Models.MovieDB;
```

Comment: Thanks is good, but don't forget to mark his answer as accepted right answer (gives him points)

Answer (score 0):

I recompiled but that did not fix the issue for me and yes I am doing the same thing and ran into the same exact issue.  The problem for me was caused by visual web developer not being able to connect to my Movies database. I had to change the definition of my connectionString within web.config like this:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"connectionString="Data Source=c:\sites\w3schools_demo\MvcDemo2\MvcDemo2\App_Data\Movies.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

If you are having this issue you will need to change the "Data Source" path to point to your Movies.sdf database file.